# Coreldraw: Total Area inside Curve

Tags: corel-draw, bezier-curve, mathematics

There's a total length measurement on CorelDraw when selecting a curve. Is there a way to also get the area inside the curve?

Comment: In CorelDraw forums something which looks script programming is suggested several times. Instead of it you can try a workaround. Make a strokeless full white fill version of your path. Place it  on a black rectangle. Rasterize the image. Open it in PhotoPaint and check its average color by sampling with the eyedropper the whole image area. Let's say you get R=G=B=103 of 255. Calculate in percents 103/255. That's 40,4% So, the white shape has area 40,4% of the area of the image. It can have error as much as 0,4% (=1/255). Hopefully someone writes - not a workaround, but a proper answer.

Comment: Save the file as SVG, and open it in inkscape and use the extension to compute the area.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this plugin for CorelDraw, but I can't test it since I don't use corelDraw. https://reproscripts.com/coreldraw/info-lib/perimeter-and-area/ - I have no connection with the developers or website.